# Warmup Requests on NodeJS causing corruption?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I have a node server running in App Engine standard using a custom domain. Everything works fine.

When I deploy a new version there is a huge latency spike as the old instances are stopped and new ones started.

From reading the docs, it would appear that I need to:

1. Enable warmup requests by adding to app.yaml
   inbound_services:

   - warmup
2. Create a handler for /_ah/warmup
3. Deploy new version without promoting: gcloud deploy --no-promote app.yaml
4. From the App Engine versions page, use Migrate to move traffic from old to new

I'm new to App Engine, and the docs are vague so I'm have questions and a major problem:

1. What is the point of the /_ah/warmup handler? Since I initialize everything I need to when the node app starts, there is nothing for this handler to do.
2. Is the handler optional? I assume yes since I read somewhere that a 404 response would be OK.
3. If it's not optional, what response is expected?
4. This is the biggie!:

I've tried this (omitting the handler). The Migrate button becomes available and appears to migrate traffic to the new version HOWEVER, after a while my site starts failing. The problem is different after each Migrate -  one time was corrupt/invalid HTML, another a JavaScript syntax error, another the entire site was wrapped inside a PRE tag in HTML I didn't write! The only way I've found to "fix" the corruption is to remove inbound_services: -warmup from app.yaml & re-deploy

To make it even weirder, the corruption only happens if the site is accessed from the custom domain. If I hit the appspot.com address everything is OK

The same code has been running fine for over a year on a traditional web server.

My head hurts. Any help/insight gratefully received

Answer (score 1):

The warmup requests aren't usually involved in new version deployment scenarios (they might, though, if your live traffic level at the time are too high to be handled by a single instance). They are only involved when you already have have at least one instance running and new instances need to be started to handle incoming traffic increases (with the same version as the running instances!) - no live traffic will be directed to the new instances until they successfully handle the warmup requests, thus indicating that they are ready to handle real user requests.

Yes, the warmup requests are optional. Not using the warmup requests would cause latency increases when dynamic scaling launches additional instances to handle traffic increases. But if you decide to not use them make sure you also do **not** enable the warmup inbound service. In other words the measures 1 and 2 in your list belong together, either you perform both, or none of them.

Performing 1 without 2 *might* cause some outages during deployments: if GAE decides to start multiple instances during the traffic migration it might send warmup requests to some of the instances, these requests will fail because there is no warmup handler, leading GAE to declare the instances unhealthy and attempting to restart them. You can check the [Instances](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/instances) screen on the developer console, selecting the newly deployed service version and the **Instances** graph and looking for the **Created** and **Active** figures to check this theory. But even if confirmed, I'm unsure if such events could explain the symptoms you described.

Only measures 3 and 4 in your list are relevant for reducing the latency during deployment of new versions. Normally there should be no traffic loss when these steps are used, provided, of course, that the new version is not faulty. At least that's the theory.